# Change Metro Bundler Host for VPN Compatibility

Tags: reactjs, react-native, vpn

I have recently tried running a React Native app that is in development on a machine connected to a VPN.  The Metro bundler fails to start:

I have tried to specify a local host by starting the project with `react-native start --host=0.0.0.0`, the result is the following error:

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                              │
│  Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.                                         │
│                                                                              │
│  Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to        │
│  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer.               │
│                                                                              │
│  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                    │
│                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:8081
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1360:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1401:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1510:7)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:142:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

If I enter http://0.0.0.0:8081 in my web browser, I get a page that says:

> React Native packager is running.

If I disable the VPN, everything starts happily...but I'd prefer to not need to disable the VPN when an app needs to be launched.  Am I using a command wrong or are the VPN settings that need to be changed?

I am on MacOS 10.14.3

VPN is PIA using their app, but this has happened using TunnelBlick with OpenVPN as well.